# How to change Android drawable icon manually?

Tags: xamarin

I use Visual Studio and debug on android device. I try to change to default application icon that seen when I build on android device. I have manually changed the Resources / drawable icon's bitmap. But when I debug, my new icon doesn't appear on android device although I have rebuild in Visual Studio. What can I do to refresh the `application icon`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The launcher icon, usually called `ic_launcher.png` exists in different folders for different resolutions (drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi) If you changed the icon in only one of the folders Android may use an icon from the folder which has the best resolution for your device.

You need to change it in all folders and your android device will show the correct icon based on your device resolution.

I assume the icon is already specified in the Activity attribute:

```
[Activity(Label = "BarcodeViewer", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", MainLauncher = true)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the image in all drawable folders. Then, ensure you have set the correct image as the launcher image in Android Manifest file in Properties folder

[image]